# Suppose that $E$ and $F$ are two events?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $E$ and $F$ are two events and that $P(E\cap F)= 0.4$ and $P(E)= 0.8$. What is $P(F\mid E)$ ?

Comment: Basic formula calculation, recall that $\Pr(A|B)$ is defined to be $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$  (when $\Pr(B)\ne 0$).

Answer (score 2):

$P(F\mid E) = \dfrac{P(F\cap E)}{P(E)}=\dfrac{0.4}{0.8} = \dfrac{1}{2}$